Find Source, Join, Subquery Tables from a PL/SQL code using python
I have a plsql code,
I want a python code which will help me to find source, join and sub query tables and subquery join tables. Kindly consider that the plsql code would get changed according to the requirement.
Output would be like,
{'source_table': ['schema_name.table1 (rfslt)'], 
 'join_tables': ['schema_name.table2 (b)', 'table3 (doogal)', 'tab_time (d)'],
 'subquery_table': ['schema_name.table6 (e)']}
'subquery_join_table': ['schema_name.table7 (h)']}
{'source_tables': ['table1 (a)'], 
 'join_tables': ['table2 (b)', 'table3 (c)', 'table4 (d)']}
{'source_tables': ['table1 (a)'], 
 'join_tables': ['table2 (b)', 'table3 (c)']}

Below is the plsql code which have and from which I need to find the output mentioned above.
Insert into tabs 
Select * from (Select * from 
schema_name.table1 rfslt
LEFT OUTER JOIN schema_name.table2 b ON rfslt.key = b.key
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 doogal ON REPLACE(rfslt.code_c, ' ', '') = doogal.code_derived
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select *
    from schema_name.table6 e
    left join schema_name.table7 h on h.id = e.id order by h.change_name) muk ON rfslt.id=muk.id
) prems
WHERE choose1 = 1
) a,
tab_time b
WHERE TRUNC(a.ok_date) = b.g_date(+);

Insert into tab 
Select a.* 
from table1 a
left join table2 b on (a.col1 = b.col1)
left join table3 c on (a.col2 = c.col2)
inner join table4 d on (b.col3 = d.col3)
Where a.col4 = 'TEST';

Insert into tab 
Select case when a.col1 = 'text' then 'Next on top' end d_col1 
from (Select * from table1 tbl where tbl.col0 = 'sample') a, 
table2 b, 
(Select * from table3 tbl3 where col0 in (select col0 from table4 order by col8) c 
Where a.col1 = b.col1(+) and a.col2 = 'TEST' and a.col3 = c.col3;

I have tried the below code to acheive the requirement.
import re

def extract_join_tables(sql_code):
    join_tables = []
    
    # Regular expression to match explicit JOIN statements
    join_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:LEFT|RIGHT|INNER|OUTER)?\s*JOIN\s+(?:\((?:[^()]|\((?:[^()]+|\([^()]*\))*\))*\)|[^\s(]+)\s+(?:\b(?:AS\s+)?(\w+)\b)?\s+ON', re.IGNORECASE)
    
    # Regular expression to match simple table references in the FROM clause
    from_pattern = re.compile(r'\bFROM\s+(?:\((?:[^()]|\((?:[^()]+|\([^()]*\))*\))*\)|[^\s(]+)\s+(?:\b(?:AS\s+)?(\w+)\b)?(?:,|$)', re.IGNORECASE)
    
    # Find all JOIN statements
    matches = join_pattern.findall(sql_code)
    for match in matches:
        if match[0]:  # match[0] contains the table name, match[1] contains the alias (if any)
            join_tables.append(match[0])
    
    # Find all simple table references in the FROM clause
    matches = from_pattern.findall(sql_code)
    for match in matches:
        if match[0]:  # match[0] contains the table name, match[1] contains the alias (if any)
            join_tables.append(match[0])
    
    return join_tables

plsql_code = """
Insert into tabs 
Select * from (Select * from 
schema_name.table1 rfslt
LEFT OUTER JOIN schema_name.table2 b ON rfslt.key = b.key
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 doogal ON REPLACE(rfslt.code_c, ' ', '') = doogal.code_derived
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select *
    from schema_name.table6 e
    left join schema_name.table7 h on h.id = e.id order by h.change_name) muk ON rfslt.id=muk.id
) prems
WHERE choose1 = 1
) a,
tab_time b
WHERE TRUNC(a.ok_date) = b.g_date(+);
"""

join_tables = extract_join_tables(plsql_code)

print("Join Tables and References:")
for table in join_tables:
    print(table)


I tried to test the regex on regex101. The join_pattern and from_pattern works well and identifies matches. So I am unsure why it is getting stuck when finding all matches.

Do you see any errors or different outputs using your code snippet? I was trying to execute that but it is getting stuck at matches = from_pattern.findall(sql_code) line.

I have not see anything as such.

I wanted to know whether you are able to execute your Python code successfully. If yes, what was the current output? if not, what is the issue you are facing while executing it?

No, I cannot be able to run this as this is getting stuck and no output it is showing.

Ofcourse you can still try to fix the fat regex, or you can use the tool that does a lot of things for you.
Have you tried to get execution plan of your query, put it to an varchar variable, and write a simplier decoding procedure ?
For example, for that query:
select prod_category, avg(amount_sold)
from sales s, products p
where p.prod_id = s.prod_id
group by prod_category;

You would get an result:
------------------------------------------
 Id   Operation              Name   
------------------------------------------
   0  SELECT STATEMENT              
   1   HASH GROUP BY                
   2    HASH JOIN                   
   3     TABLE ACCESS FULL   PRODUCTS
   4     PARTITION RANGE ALL        
   5      TABLE ACCESS FULL  SALES  
------------------------------------------

Which is forsure easier to get the data from in compare to your attempts.
You can read more about it here: Oracle- displaying execution plan

Apologies for the confusion. I am pretty much aware of the explain plan. Thank you. Here I am not worried about the plslq code. I just need to find out the source, join tables from a plsql code. Code can be written in various way. So, my code should be that much intelligent enough to produce exact output whether the sql statement contains explicit or implicit joins or multi-level sub query in it.
